# PowerShell: programmatically access script documentation

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Is there a way to programmatically load the documentation of a .ps1 script file outside of commands like get-help?  In other words, can text defined under .SYNOPSIS, .DESCRIPTION, etc. be accessed programmatically other than filtering the string output of get-help itself?

Among other things, I'm trying to find where I have gaps in documentation coverage in my script library. I'd also like to be able to display lists of certain scripts with their synopsis attached.

Comment: Do you want to access the help for a cmdlet, or access what is effectively in-line doc by way of a comment block at the start? You could add a parameter that just displays help (a `-h` switch for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, those are all accessible. `Get-Help` returns (just like any other cmdlet) an object, and the default rendering of that object is what you see in the console.

However, if you pump `get-help`'s output through `format-list`, like this:

```
get-help get-childitem | format-list
```

You'll get a list of name-value pairs of the properties. To get the synopsis, you can do the following:

```
get-help get-childitem |select-object -property synopsis
```

And the output:

```
Synopsis
--------
Gets the files and folders in a file system drive.
```

If your `.ps1` file has no cmdlets defined in it (your comment-based help covers the whole script), `get-help file.ps1|select synopsis` should work. Otherwise, you'll need to "dot-source" the files to load the cmdlet definitions into memory, then use `get-help` as above.

Comment: Interestingly you have to explicitly do get-help for this to work - if you use the 'help' alias you just get text.